# Why is my Django loop displaying the same image in svg viewbox?

Tags: django, svg, django-models, django-templates

I am using the django framework and trying to display images from the model in a polygon. For this I am using svg. Currently it just displays the smae image multiple times instead of displaying all images in the database. Here is my code:

```
{% if images %}


<section id="gallery">
     <ul id="hexGrid">
  {% for image in images %}
  <li class="hex">

  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
    <image xlink:href="{{image.src.url}}" x="-25" width="150" height="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <polygon id="hex" points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img)"/>
  </svg>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
  </section>

{% else %}

<p>
  No Posts
</p>
{% endif %}
```

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models


class Images(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    src = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', null=True, verbose_name="")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are the queryset and the view?

Comment: All patterns generated in the loop have the same id="img". You need to make the id values unique.